# How to add multiple identical nodes to ListView

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocosbuilder

I try add Node to ListView so:

```
auto nodeToAdd = loadCcbAsNode("fileccb.ccbi").get();

for (size_t i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    listView->addChild(nodeToAdd);       // it's cocos2d::ui::ListView
                                         // which i load to scene
}
```

But get so error:

> CCASSERT(child->_parent == nullptr, "child already added. It can't be added again");

What i need do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
{
    NodePtr nodeToAdd = loadCcbAsNode("fileccb.ccbi");
    nodeToAdd->setPosition(0,i*45);                      // 45-size of height my node
                                                         // need to bias
    listView->addChild(nodeToAdd.get());
}
```

as it turned out, when i create `auto nodeToAdd = loadCcbAsNode("fileccb.ccbi").get();`, nodeToAdd has a type Node, but cocos has special smart pointer NodePtr, and which i calling value with type of NodePtr, it's pointer automatically increments the counter by one, and Node this does not.

Comment: Will it work if you move `NodePtr nodeToAdd = loadCcbAsNode("fileccb.ccbi");` out of the loop?

Comment: Don't work. Also call assert `CCASSERT(child->_parent == nullptr, "child already added. It can't be added again");`

Answer (score 0):

Are those nodes simply clonable? If yes, you can add an identical copy at each iteration:

```
auto nodeToAdd = loadCcbAsNode("fileccb.ccbi").get();
listView->addChild(nodeToAdd);

for(size_t i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
    listView->addChild(nodeToAdd->clone());
}
```

Or, alternatively, if it's a one-time action, load a few instances on the go:

```
for(size_t i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    listView->addChild(loadCcbAsNode("fileccb.ccbi").get());
}
```

Comment: cocos2d::node haven't method clone, and 2 variant adding just one node to list. it's not helped

Comment: Okay, try to use `new cocos2d::node(*nodeToAdd)` instead of `->clone()` it lacks.

Comment: Concerning variant 2, in your own response you're doing practically the same but setting position. Is it ListView does not automatically handle its nodes' positions and you have actually seen nine identical nodes on top of one another?